# Render a loader while files are sent to the server in react.js

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, design-patterns, promise, loader

I'm sending XML files to the server using react.js and I want to render a loader until the server make a response.

I tried with one file component and it works. But I want to make it with three different files, each one with a different size and response time.

I have something like this.

```
class UploadFiles extends Component {
  state = { 
  isLoading: null }

 // Omitted code for upload files to the state


 uploadData(file){
 // Omitted Code <- Asynchronous function, each file has a different
                    response time.
 }


  handleSubmit(){

    this.setState({isLoading:true}, () => {
     uploadData(file1).then(res => {
         // Do something with the response
     this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }

    this.setState({isLoading:true}, () => {
     uploadData(file2).then(res => {
         // Do something with the response
     this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }

    this.setState({isLoading:true}, () => {
     uploadData(file3).then(res => {
         // Do something with the response
     this.setState({isLoading: false});
    }


  }

  render() { 
    return (
   const {isLoading} = this.state;
   if(isLoading){
     return <Loader/> 
   }else {
   return (
   <div>
   <FileComponent />
   <FileComponent/>
   <FileComponent/>
   <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>submit</button>
   </div> );}
  }
}
```

This kind of works, but if the file1 is uploaded to the server more faster than the other two files the Loader component is not still rendered.
I need that the loader is still rendered until the three files are uploaded to the server.

There is some correct/clean way to make this?
Note: I need to send the files one by one to the server. The server only receives one file per request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're spawning 3 parallel uploads and as you already observed first one that finishes sets `isLoading = false`.

To wait for several promises, use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) like this:

```
this.setState({isLoading:true}, () => {
    Promise
        .all([
             uploadData(file1)
             uploadData(file2),
             uploadData(file3)
        ])
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({isLoading:false})
        })
});
```